# Why my Searchbar stay at the top only if I use it?

Tags: swift, xcode, list

I have a tableView containing a list. I use a searchbar to filter the data. When I touch chararcter in the search text, I can display filtered datas and the searchbar stay at the top when I scroll. But, if I don't use it (searchbar is empty), when I scroll, the searchbar is the first line of the list and disappear when I scroll down. You can find a part of code there :

```
class Liste*****Active: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating,
UISearchBarDelegate,RecupListe*****ModelProtocol {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    definesPresentationContext = true

    ListeTab*****.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    self.ListeTab*****.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

}


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    // If we haven't typed anything into the search bar then do not filter the results
    if searchController.searchBar.text! == "" {
        filtered*****s = feedItems
    } else {
        // Filter the results
        filtered*****s = feedItems.filter { ($0 as! *****Model).nom*****!.lowercased().contains(searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) } as! [*****Model] as NSArray
    }

    self.ListeTab*****.reloadData()
}
```

Nothing is defined in storyboard.

Did I forgot part of code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your search bar is embedded in navigation bar, you need to override this behavior:

`navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false`

**Update**

You use searcher as table header.

`ListeTab*****.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`

So that's basically an issue -- your search bar is part of the table content that's why it's getting scrolled. To avoid that you need to get your search bar out of the `tableView`.

Possible solutions:

- Embedding `searchBar` into the navigation controller header view.
- Adding a `searchBar` as a separate view on top of the table view in the view hierarchy

Comment: Hello @Inokey, thanks for your answer. The searchbar still disappear when I scroll

Comment: How do you add search bar?

Comment: I don't remember where I found the part of code to add the searchbar. I only use the code in my question.

Comment: I used a searchbar as a separate view on top of the tableview. It's Ok, thanks...  now the problem is to delete data from the filtered list... ;-)